# Boost Asio type to use for both unix-socket and tcp socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

We have a boost asio based networking code, which connects to a remote side.
The local side could be either a tcp4 socket or a unix socket.

Is there a typename to use that could hold both of these type of boost sockets? (e.g. something like a base class for both?).
Currently our code use
  `boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket` for tcp socket, and
  `boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket` for a unix socket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, there's a dedicated `ip::tcp::socket` type for tcp sockets.
As for `generic::stream_protocol::socket`, it is the universal stream socket type that accepts socket protocol and family in run-time, so you can use it for the both types you need:

```
generic::stream_protocol::socket ipc(io_, generic::stream_protocol(AF_UNIX, 0));
generic::stream_protocol::socket tcp(io_, generic::stream_protocol(AF_INET, IPPROTO_TCP));
```