# Is there a generic boost::XXX::stream_protocol::socket that can be move-constructed from local::stream_protocol::socket or ip::tcp::socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I am designing a class that will talk to a peer over a stream_protocol::socket that somebody else creates and passes to the constructor.  (So somebody else will connect or accept a TCP connection, a local stream socket, or something like that, and give the socket to my class constructor.  My constructor will **move** the socket to a member variable and then use it to talk to whoever is on the other end.  The caller will be left with an empty socket (because the guts have been moved to my class object))

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123980/boost-asio-type-to-use-for-both-unix-socket-and-tcp-socket) seems like the right idea, but I can't get the constructor signature correct.  I'm trying:

```
class foo {
  public:
    /**/ foo( generic::stream_protocol::socket &&s ) : pSock( s ) { }
  private:
    generic::stream_protocol::socket pSock;
} ;
```

but g++ complains that I'm using an implicitly deleted constructor.  (I think I just have the wrong syntax to choose the move constructor that the docs say exists.)

```
bt.hpp: In constructor âbt::peer::peer(boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket&&)â:
bt.hpp:24:31: error: use of deleted function âboost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol>::basic_stream_socket(const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol>&)â
                    : pSock( s )
                               ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:31:0,
                 from utp.hpp:22,
                 from main.cc:54:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp:46:7: note: âboost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol>::basic_stream_socket(const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol>&)â is implicitly declared as deleted because âboost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::generic::stream_protocol>â declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
 class basic_stream_socket
       ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

I plan to use the class like this:

```
ip::tcp::socket tcp_conn( ... );
tcp_conn.connect( ... );
local::stream_protocol::socket local_conn( ... );
local_conn.connect( ... );

foo socket_talker1( tcp_conn );
foo socket_talker2( local_conn );
// Now socket_talker1 and socket_talker2 can talk to the remote parties, and tcp_conn and local_conn are invalid.
```

Comment: The compiler complains you are using a deleted *copy* constructor, not move constructor. You probably need to use std::move somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you forgot about `std::move()`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee5a44c95a7382cd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace impl {
    using namespace boost::asio;

    class foo {
          public:
            /**/ foo(generic::stream_protocol::socket &&s) : pSock(std::move(s)) {}

          private:
            generic::stream_protocol::socket pSock;
    };
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I need to read up on some of the new stuff in c++ (I know, it's a few years old now, but programming is not my day job!)  Thanks!